# What is the location of the nomenclature section in a scientific paper?

Tags: phd, peer-review

I received this comment from a reviewer: *“ It is better to add a nomenclature section with a list of all the used symbols and their meaning as example (DVB-T, DVB-S2, BCH, OSFBC, LDPC...), consequently the paper should be re-arranged eliminating all the definitions given in the sections”*.

**Are there any specific position for this section ?**

Answer (score 9):

The correct position for a nomenclature section is the location normally used by the journal in question. While as Paul suggests, the logical location for this should be at the *start* of the paper, in many journals, the nomenclature section is placed at the *end*, largely because it does not "look as good" to have the nomenclature section right on the first page (which is optically the "prime real estate" of the paper).

Answer (score 3):

If you add such a section, it would need to be directly after the abstract. This way, any nomenclature is explained before it is used in the main text.

Comment: Wouldn't it be after the introduction, and just before one launches into the main technical descriptions ?

Comment: One would probably also want to use abbreviations in the introduction, so a place after the abstract but before the introduction seems best to me.

Comment: it seems that is the right place for this section (after the abstract),
thank you for your help

Comment: The introduction should really come before the nomenclature section, and should explain the main ideas of the paper in terms that don't use unfamiliar nomenclature. You don't want to discourage your readers before they read the introduction.